# Print a text using default Arial-15

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm trying to play around with printing a text message, it seems I am doing everything correctly and it doesn't show any errors, but it's not printing "*Hello World*".  Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong?  I've searched around and I just cannot find a solution.  I know you can use custom fonts and put them in your assets folder, but I have been told you do not need to do this, default is Arial-15.

Here is an image of what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JQba.png

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener {
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private BitmapFont font;
    private float x, y;

    private String str;

    @Override
    public void create() {      
        float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        str = "Hello World!";
        font = new BitmapFont();

        camera = new OrthographicCamera(1, h/w);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {      
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        x = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        font.setColor(Color.RED);
        font.draw(batch, str, x/2, y/2);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are doing everything right. Maybe you could try removing the .setProjectionMatrix method. Are you sure you are calling the render method correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your code again. I marked the important lines with comments

```
@Override
public void create() {      
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    str = "Hello World!";
    font = new BitmapFont();

    // Here you are setting your viewport to width = 1, height = 0.75 for example
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(1, h/w);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
}

@Override
public void render() {      
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    x = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    font.setColor(Color.RED);
    // for a screen resolution of 800x600 you are now telling the font to draw the text at 400, 300.
    font.draw(batch, str, x/2, y/2);
    batch.end();
}
```

You are basically just using wrong coordinates. You text would be visible, if you would render it at the correct place. Try either `font.draw(batch, str, 0.5f, 0.5f);` or `camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());`.